# How do I give www-data user to a folder in my home folder?

Tags: permissions, directory, home-directory, users

I have a folder: `/home/myuser/folderA`

I want to give the www-data user write access to the above, while 'myuser' continues to have normal access (as it is myuser's home folder anyway).

Which commands do I need to use?

Note: I don't want `www-data` to have access to any other folders in `/home/myuser/`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

First, add yourself into the group `www-data`

```
usermod -a -G www-data (your username)
```

Then:

```
chgrp www-data /home/myuser/folderA
chmod g+rwxs /home/myuser/folderA
```

Should do the trick unless the permissions on your `/home/myuser` do not permit other users access.

The first command changes the group ownership of the folder to that of the webserver. The second command gives members of the `www-data` group read, write, enter-directory rights, and the group `s` flag will ensure that any files that get created inside that directory take `www-data` as the group - so if you create a file as `myuser` the `www-data` user will have access.

Nb. this also depends on the `umask` settings of both your user account and the webserver: you need to make sure that files created in folderA have group `rw` access (and directories created within need group `rwx`)

If your webserver does not have enter rights into your `/home/myuser` dir (quite sensible) then it's not going to get in there unless you do something else. Two solns:

1. `sudo mount --bind /home/myuser/folderA /var/www/mysite/folderA`  (this is an ugly hack and would have to be repeated after reboot. But a powerful trick, also can be used to make folders accessible inside SSH jails.)
2. Simply move the shared folder somewhere else, e.g. `/home/shared-stuff/folderA`.

The 2nd option is nicest. Let's say the stuff in folderA is really public and you don't care who sees it, you can set it up like

```
sudo mkdir -m777 /home/shared-stuff
```

Then you can put inside that, say, folderA with permissions as above, and folderB that www-data should not have access to with different permissions, e.g.

```
$ cd /home/shared-stuff ; ls -l
drwxrwsr-x 2 myuser www-data   4096 Jan 17 21:46 folderA
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser myuser     4096 Jan 17 21:46 folderB
```

Comment: what is `s` in `g+rwxs` ?

Comment: "Group sticky" bit. It's effect explained in para that begins with "The first..." :-)

Comment: to make binds persistent you can add in /etc/fstab ```/home/myuser/folderA /var/www/mysite/folderA    none    bind```

Comment: nerver use this way. it is security problem

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to change the username directly in apache config, this is if it's **your local machine** and you save images from somewhere else that would crush any permissions made on the folder. Also to do if you have only 1 user and don't care about www-data!

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find User and Group and put yours
`User <Your User>`
`Group <Your Group>`

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem so secure, anyone know what kind of security threats this setting will cause?

Comment: I'm quite sure it's not secure, that is why I gave the precision of Local Machine only.

Comment: This solution provides all access to apache to your folder...

Comment: I like this solution; as long as you don't use `root`, it's your private/local machine, and you have sensible permissions - especially useful if you deploy using `rsync`/`ftp` and don't use a method conducive to changing permissions, like a script.

Comment: With nginx (as opposed to apache) it would be `$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` changing `user www-data;` to `user your-username;`

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was part of artfulrobot's answer. But it was regarding apache `/var/www/html` folder. In fact, it should already belong to www-data user.

All needed was to add your user to the www-data group to be able to edit and then specify the group of this master folder. e.g.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $(whoami)
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html -R
```