# Apache: access denied because search permissions are missing

Tags: permissions, apache2

I know this question is asked a lot, but the solutions I saw didn't work for me.

I only have one virtual host enabled, and I'm trying to enable access to a folder that's not under the document root

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Alias /movies /home/username/Videos/Movies

<Directory /home/username/Videos/Movies/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I set `/etc/apache2/envvars` as follows

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=public
```

I made sure that /home/username/Videos/ and its sub folders are owned by `username:public`, set the permissions to 777 (after 775 didn't work) and made sure that user `www-data` belongs to group `public`.

Now, when I browse to `http://localhost/movies` I get

```
[Mon Apr 21 11:28:14.971844 2014] [core:error] [pid 1385:tid 140067725104896] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46603] AH00035: access to /movies/ denied (filesystem path '/home/username/Videos') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

But when I set `/etc/apache2/envvars` to run Apache under `username` (my own username) everything works fine. The problem is permission related, but I don't see how in my case; especially when I set the permissions to `777`. Any ideas?

P.S. Ubuntu version is 14.04, Apache is 2.4.7 and I didn't edit other configuration files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give www-data user to a folder in my home folder?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder)

Comment: I did everything they suggested over there, as I wrote, and it does not help

Comment: Any chance you have mounted your `/home` with ACL enabled? (there is a "+" sign at the end of the permission bits if it's the case (check with `ls -l`))

Comment: No, I didn't do it. Right now I'm running Apache under my user, so it's working, but I'd like to run it under another user for security reasons.

Comment: I'm using Linux for the first time. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTE version. I'm facing the same problem. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Do a `chmod +x` on your **user dir**, and restart apache. ***755*** permissions should work. I've had problems with *644*.

* Note that as of Ubuntu 22.04 the **user dir** has ***750*** permissions by default rather than ***755***.

Comment: Indeed, and to double check file and directory permissions, if available, you can use `namei -m /home/youruser/public_html/yourfile.ext` or try http://people.apache.org/~igalic/hacks/parsepath

Comment: to clarify, any directory you want Apache to read, must be readable for Apache user. Most likely your user home folder is not owned by you user and group, therefor you have to set 755 permissions to `/home/username` to access it with apace.

Comment: I had this problem on OSX Mac OS High Sierra and this solution worked for me.  Didn't even have to restart Apache.

Comment: After hours of searching it turns out that the permissions should be correct  for the parent directories of the DocumentRoot too. Thank you very much . BTW this does not need to restart Apache

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: @Accountantم thanks for the tip. I was setting the permission on the nested directories and forgot about the parent.

Comment: Saved my day :)

Answer (score 42):

If in the case of SELinux being the issue, rather than just disable it, [this page](http://diegobz.net/2010/03/07/enabling-apache-userdir-public_html-with-selinux-enabled-on-fedora/), [this page](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/enable-apache-userdir-with-selinux-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), and [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50641/248746) give the command to grant access:

Allows httpd read access
`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t ~/public_html/`

Allows httpd write access
`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t ~/public_html/`

Allows httpd remote calls
`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

The 3rd one allows `file_get_contents/curl` outbound calls that are disabled by SElinux by edfault.

Comment: I Was sure it was my issue.  Damn CentOS !  Thx for the command, works perfectly.

Comment: thanks, just had to replace the `~/public_html/` part with the root directory of the content I was trying to serve.

Comment: `chcon -R  -t  httpd_sys_content_t  /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/` (in my situation)

Comment: Discovered selinux can't handle simple homedirs, and only one of those features was required while the other was optional.  Thanks for the reminder as to the fix -- after the mandatory re-test period with each new release, and disappointment, I usually just hack that out in the kickstart.  Now for systemd.

Comment: This is not the best long-term way of solving this problem. `chcon` is only for temporary changes. Better is to set up a security policy using `semanage` i.e. `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/path/to/whatever(/.*)?"` which will make the change persist, say in the face of a `restorecon` command, or anything that resets SELinux file contexts.

Comment: Thanks. Helped. It's strange that that step is not described in documentation

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same problem, after hours of trying, I found a solution exactly solves the problem:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Basically, the Apache server does not only require read permissions of all files it serves, but the execution permission of all directories in the path of your virtual host.

The utility namei can be used to help find permissions problems by listing the permissions along each component of the path:

```
namei --modes /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/foo/bar.html
```

In my case, a directory in my path has the permission 700, it causes the problem. After changing it to 701, the problem was solved.

Comment: The link here is helpful because it explains the problem: One of the nodes in the directory path is missing search permissions. Use the "namei" command to find this and then "chmod" to 755.

Comment: It explain the real reason as well as solution. thanks

Comment: I suggest `namei --long` instead.

Answer (score 19):

You might have selinux enabled. Try

```
getenforce
```

If it shows "Enforcing", try

```
setenforce 0
```

and try if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Don't just disable SELinux as a fix. Fix the SELinux problems by reassigning ports or setting booleans.

Comment: This answer helps to identify that the issue is related to SELinux. But disabling it is not recommended.

Comment: Just want to point out that, Setting SELinux to Permissive and Setting it to Disabled are not the same thing. In case of first, it will still warn you. 

Its a good step during development to first set SELinux to permissive, to isolate the issue first, then make necessary changes to SELinux settings once everything else works fine.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of granting access of the home directories `~` and `~/public_html` (*e.g.* by `chmod 755 ...`) to all users, an alternative is to add the [apache2 user](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865) (usually `www-data` for Ubuntu) to the personal group of the current user (the group with the same name as the user name):

```
sudo adduser www-data $(whoami)
sudo service apache2 reload
```

(assuming `~/public_html` belongs to the default user group.)

This matters when there are multiple users and it's important that the users are not allowed to access each others home folders.

Comment: before this I tried even chown -R www-data:www-data to home but that did not work. however as you suggested adding user to www-data group work. :|

Comment: This works for me, when I created a virtualhost file for a test domain on Ubuntu 22.04 with `DocumentRoot /home/abc/web/test/`, then with these two commands, I can access `http://test`.

Comment: instead of whoami .. using the name of the owner is safer way in the first command listed above, because the person might be signed in as a different user, instead of the owner of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue when I was trying to run apache in a docker container on an Ubuntu 16.04 host that was using the 4.4 kernel instead of 4.10.

Once I ran this command on the host and re-deployed, I was fine:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: I have bumped into this problem, but with the strange effect that I can `chmod` or `chown` inside the container, and it suppresses the Apache 403 errors for a while, only to revert some time later. There is no intervening container restart or other substantive change that could be the cause of this, as far as I can tell. Since I am indeed running 16.04, I tried installing this binary, and my 403s are held at bay for now. I will keep a beady eye on it, and thanks!