# Setting up SFTP to log in to server with Filezilla and access files outside my home directory

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, sftp, wordpress

I have an ec2 instance on AWS which already installed a few Wordpress-es in it.  I want to set things up to let more people handle their own projects, with me also being able to go into the server using terminal if I still want to.

I have been following tutorials such as
[How to setup a restricted SFTP server on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu) and a few others.  I figured all of them just teach users how to `sftp` into their own home folder, also the steps keep saying `addUser` but some users already existed and removing them might cause some issue.

How can I give existing users the permission to use SFTP for Wordpress projects?

Let's say all my Wordpress projects are already under `/var/www/` which has already been set up with `www-data:www-data`.

Really new with setting things like this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @pa4080 Your answer is quite lengthy and confusing, wouldn't it just be easier to show Op how to set up SSH and Give their users public keys?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff the question is not about that. I'm assuming this is already achieved: *I figured all of them just teaches how to sftp into their own home folder...*  The answer contains about 7 sentences.

Comment: Hi, Dora, I know you've asked the question longtime ago, but maybe you will like the update of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Recently I've converted this answer into a useful script and extensively start using it with VSCode and its SSH abilities. The script is now available at GitHub: [bindfs-to-home-bash](https://github.com/metalevel-tech/bindfs-to-home-bash).

---

Here I'm assuming you are able to ssh/sftp to your user's home directory successfully and you want to edit (with your user) files and folders under `/var/www` that are owned by `user` and `:group` - `www-data:www-data` (without changing their ownership).

Here I'm assuming also the topic [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/566421) doesn't cover you needs. For example you don't want to change the permissions under `/var/www`.

I think the most easiest and clear way to solve this task is to mount `/var/www` (or certain directory inside) into your user's home directory and change the owner to your user and :group. This could be achieved by the tool `bindfs`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install bindfs
```

---

Here we will mount the entire directory `/var/www` in a directory called also `www/` and located in your user's home directory.

```
mkdir "$HOME/www"
sudo bindfs -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g) --create-for-user=www-data --create-for-group=www-data /var/www "$HOME/www"
```

- The command substitutions `$(id -u)` and `$(id -g)` will return the UID and GID of the current user.
- If you want to execute the above command for another user use `$(id -u <user>)` and `$(id -g <user>)`. Where `<user>` is an actual username.
- For more details about the arguments used with `bindfs` read its manual page - [`man bindfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bindfs.1.html).
- If you want to un-mount `~/www` (`$HOME/www`) use the command:

  ```
    sudo fusermount -u ~/www
  ```

---

To mount `/var/www` in `~/www` automatically during the system startup add the following line into the bottom of `/etc/fstab`:

```
bindfs#/var/www /home/<user>/www fuse force-user=<uid>,force-group=<gid>,create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data 0 0
```

- **Note:** you should replace `<user>` with the actual username; also should replace `<uid>` and `<gid>` with the actual UID and GID of the `<user>`, you can find them by the commands: `id -u <user>` and `id -u <user>`.
- To see the result reboot the system or execute:

  ```bsh
    sudo mount -a    # maybe you should execute `sudo fusermount -u ~/www` first
  ```

---

Here is animated demo how this works:

[image]

The only limitation of this approach that I found is when you change the ownership of the bind directory this will change the ownership also for the source directory. For example the next command is not a good idea:

```
chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/www
```

Maybe there is a suitable option for the `bindfs` command that will prevent this to happen, but I can't tell that at the moment.

Notes:

- [SOS Directory Nightmare - Possible for a directory to have two different users with full access?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1107854/566421)
- [What is the "t" letter in the output of "ls -ld /tmp"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/432699/566421)
- [How do I give www-data user to a folder in my home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/244406/566421)
- [Permissions problems with /var/www/html and my own home directory for a website document root](https://askubuntu.com/q/767504/566421)

Comment: I believe I am understanding the logic and so on but, let's say if I am setting this up for another user? I tried replacing `$USER` with another user's name but gives me something like this `Not a valid group ID:`

Comment: the user's name does exist though, I am able to use `filezilla` to sftp in with the username and password

Comment: Hi, @Dora, use the command `id filezilla` to fin to which group the user `filezilla` belongs to. Then use this group where it is needed. If you want post the output of `id filezilla`, maybe I could help.

Comment: oh oops by `filezilla` I meant the ftp software with gui.  anyways I used `id username` as you mentioned and this is the outcome `uid=1002(username) gid=1002(ftpaccess) groups=1002(ftpaccess),33(www-data)

`

Comment: @Dora: have you read this great topic: [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/566421) ... The approach that I proposed here is different, but in this way you will be able to manipulate with the files more fluently.

Comment: I do like the way you proposed, but the avoid using sudo has to do with why I get the error of `Not a valid group id:`?

Comment: @Dora: According to the current answer: (1) the `bindfs` command should be: `sudo bindfs -u username -g ftpaccess --create-for-user=www-data --create-for-group=www-data /var/www /path-to/mount-point` (2) the `etc/fstab` directive: `bindfs#/var/www /path-to/mount-point fuse force-user=username,force-group=ftpaccess,create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data 0 0`

Comment: @Dora, I've updated the answer. Actually instead of the `user` and its `group` names you can use their IDs - UID and GID - to find them use: `id -u username` and `id -g username`.

Comment: I'm happy to help you, @Dora!