# allow permission to apache html to both www-data and user

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, apache2, php

I am using mkdir function in php and I use `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/` than I am able to mkdir folder. But than I am not able to edit any file in `/var/www/html/` . So I tried both below method :

`sudo chown -R www-data:username /var/www/html/` and

`sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html/`

But In that mkdir stops working giving permission denied error. 
How to give permission to both www-data and myself both.

Comment: In the first answer, look at Solution 1 as a possible fix for your problem.

Comment: Different approach is shown here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024308/566421