# Wordpress permissions conflict with www-data and ftp

Tags: permissions, nginx, vsftpd, www

Running: Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx 1.14

I read somewhere that running Wordpress in 'fs_direct' mode is a security threat, so I wanted to completely scrap that idea and stick to a local ftp server instead. 
Here's the issue, I have the two users, www-data (what the server can run/see) and webftp (what Wordpress can upload through vsftpd). I can't have www-data run full permissions for obvious security reasons, but I need webftp to be able to write.

What is the BEST way to run these permissions side-by-side so they don't interfere with one another?

While I am good at most things linux, linux permissions are very confusing to me, so please be patient :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up SFTP to log in to server with Filezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024194/setting-up-sftp-to-log-in-to-server-with-filezilla) In addition if www-data doesn't have full permissions to the WordPress directory you wouldn't  be able to update WordPress and it's plugins through the web interface - the solution in this case is to use [wp-cli ](https://wp-cli.org/).

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks so much for your answer. I set everything up, and everything is binding properly. However, now vsftpd complains when I log in, "500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()" and I am unable to log in. However, I have full rwx permissions when I log in through ssh. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind. Was able to work around this by further messing with the config file

Comment: Happy to help :) Is there any special purpose to use `vsftpd` instead `sftp` that comes by default with `openssh-server`?

Comment: @pa4080 No haha. I use my sftp server for other stuff and I change the configuration all the time. Just wanted something I could set up and forget about